# What is the best practice for storing image varbinary(max) data in a database table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, locking

I have a table that stores images that range in size between 16-100 KB each.  Since the images are so small, I've taken [Microsoft's advice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and not used the FILESTREAM data type.  The table is constructed simply:

```
CREATE TABLE Screenshot(
         Id bigint NOT NULL,
         Data varbinary(max) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Screenshot PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
Id ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
   STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
   IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
   ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The table is heavily inserted into (2 million records in the past week) and rarely selected.  The key is using a [hilo algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282099/whats-the-hi-lo-algorithm), so for the most part new rows are added at the end.

I've been having problems when a lot of processes try to insert into this table because of locking and contention.  Queries are timing out from waiting for locks.

Should I migrate this table to its own file group and drive?  How can I improve the insert performance and decrease contention in this type of situation?

Comment: Why are inserts blocking reads? What version of SQL Server are you using? Or do you mean `insert`s are timing out?

Comment: Inserts are blocking other inserts.  The error I'm getting is: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.  I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: what is the rationale behind `ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS=ON`?

Comment: There is no rationale.

Comment: Maybe it was auto-generated for you? (`ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS=ON`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try changing the id generation so inserts are not contending with each other, or consider setting `ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF`, noting the [implications](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic728780-360-1.aspx#bm728873) for index maintenance (which are probably only relevant if you are also doing updates)

Comment: I couldn't find any literature that would help me understand why ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF would help me with insert contention.  I want to take an evidence-based approach to solving this problem, but I don't know enough to do that.  Any suggestions on where to go?

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned FILESTREAM, I expect you are using SQL Server 2008. Instead of guessing what is the bottleneck and how to improve, you should identify it using Extended Events and doing a load test [http://www.datamanipulation.net/sqlquerystress/] on this activity.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sqlos/archive/2008/07/18/debugging-slow-response-times-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Once you identify the bottleneck, figuring out the solution will always be easy, correct and right on the money.

Comment: Excellent advice, Sankar.  Thanks for the reminder.